# Error "PineconeClient: Project name not set. Call init() first." when using TS client @pinecone-database/pinecone v0.0.8

Tags: typescript

I'm using the official Pinecone typescript client [@pinecone-database/pinecone v0.0.8](https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client) and I execute it's method `Index()`,  I get an error:

```
PineconeClient: Project name not set. Call init() first.
```

My code:

```js
const pinecone = new PineconeClient();
await pinecone.init({
  // (I double checked the env variables are ok):
  environment: process.env.PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT,
  apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY,
});
const index = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX_NAME); // here, the error is thrown!
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

We get an error `PineconeClient: Project name not set. Call init() first.`, because  the call `pinecone.init()` was unsuccessfull (however it failed silently and didn't throw any error). It could be caused by various reasons, e.g. `fetch` is undefined (b/c you're using NodeJS version older than 18 and not using `node-fetch` replacement package) OR the given API key or environment are incorrect.

#### Explanation

I investigated the source code of Pinecone client. And here's the explanation:

Behind the scenes, the `pinecone.init()` calls the Pinecone's endpoint `/actions/whoami` using the native `fetch()`. The request is sent with 2 parameters: environment and API key; and it should return your Pinecone's project ID. For more see [source code of PineconeClient](https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client/blob/aa99c9728f5f5521d5e2e8c3ab3cb3cfb1edbb82/src/index.ts#L91-L101).

Later on, if project's ID is undefined, the call for `pinecone.Index()` [will throw an error](https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client/blob/aa99c9728f5f5521d5e2e8c3ab3cb3cfb1edbb82/src/index.ts#L129). The project's ID is essential, because [it constitutes a part of the base url for calls to the actual Pinecone API](https://github.com/pinecone-io/pinecone-ts-client/blob/aa99c9728f5f5521d5e2e8c3ab3cb3cfb1edbb82/src/index.ts#L133).

This call might be unsuccessfull due to various reasons, e.g. `fetch` is not defined (in Node versions prior to 18) OR api key or environment are wrong. Unfortunately Pinecone doesn’t throw any error during this initialization of the client. Only later, when trying to use PineconeClient’s methods, we get a confusing error `PineconeClient: Project name not set. Call init() first.`

Comment: what is the workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a problem in the pinecone 0.0.8 package.

I experienced the same issue when I have `"@pinecone-database/pinecone": "0.0.8",` in package.json

Once I updated the pinecone version from `0.0.8` to `0.0.12` and run `pnpm install`, I am able to connect and interact with `pinecone`

Output of `pnpm install`:

```
dependencies:
- @pinecone-database/pinecone 0.0.8
+ @pinecone-database/pinecone 0.0.12 (0.0.14 is available)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple mistake that I made that was giving this error:

I forgot to put an `await` before the `pinecone.init()` call.

Just in case someone else gets here looking for a solution and everything else checks out like it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was passing in a placeholder text YOUR_PINECONE_API_KEY instead of my actual API key

Answer (score 0):

First login into your Pinecone Account, Click on Indexes menu , Now you can find your index details just below your index name like

```
pine-*****.svc.us-west4-gcp-free.pinecone.io
```

***** - represents your project name and

pine  - represents my index name

you specify your project name as given in your account.

It worked for me!